# Looking for a Software that can record multiple instances of a program

Tags: screen-recording

I am working for a company which fights with non repeatable error messages. For that reason we need a software solution which allows us to record multiple instances of our software. Our software is starting additional windows, so we can't use OBS cause it is only capable to record one window of our software at a time.

I hope I didn't forget any relevant details and hope you can help me.

Edit: Forgot to mention that a whole screen recording is not a solution.

Comment: You want to screencast (record) several window at the same time, do I understand correctly? I guess it would output two video files, or maybe a single video file where both windows are juxtaposed. What operating system? Linux/Mac/etc?

Comment: So, the software has to detect the appearance of new windows ? Possibly with a given title? Personally, I would add debug trace to the code. Get the NewWindow() function to stack dump to a file. Better yet, dedicate a PC to running it in the debugger, for days or weeks if necessary, and breakpoint that function. A video solution is only going to show you a new window launching; it will not tell you why.